# Find the characteristic polynomial |$\lambda - AI $| for this $5 \times 5$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

> Find the characteristic polynomial |$\lambda - AI $| for the $5\times 5$ matrix
>
> $$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 
>   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
>   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
>   0 & 0& 0 & 1 & 0\\
>   0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
>   10^{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
>   \end{matrix}\right)$$

My attempts:

$$A - \lambda I   = \left(\begin{matrix} 
  -\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 &  -\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0&  -\lambda & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & 0 &  -\lambda & 1\\
  10^{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\lambda \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

From my thinking, the characteristic polynomial |$\lambda - AI $| for the $5\times 5$ matrix is -$\lambda ^5$.

Is it true or false? Any hints/solution will be appreciated. Please help me. Thanks you.

Comment: You are missing one term: the broken diagonal of $1$'s along with ...

Comment: Recognize it as the transpose of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $x^5-10^{10}$.

Comment: Wrong definition of characteristic polynomial. Not only should these be monic, also $\lambda$ traditionally is used for eigenvalues, which are scalars; it cannot then also be used as indeterminate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing a Laplace expansion along the first column, you get that the determinant of that matrix is equal to\begin{align}-\lambda\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&1&0&0\\0&-\lambda&1&0\\0&0&-\lambda&1\\0&0&0&-\lambda\end{vmatrix}+10^{10}\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0&0\\-\lambda&1&0&0\\0&-\lambda&1&0\\0&0&-\lambda&1\end{vmatrix}=-\lambda^5+10^{10}.\end{align}

Comment: +1 good explanation

Answer (score 2):

If the characteristic polynomial is $-\lambda^5$, you are suggesting that $0$ is an eigenvalue and the matrix is singular. However, it should be clear that the rows are linearly independent and hence the matrix is nonsingular.

To find it characteristic polynomial, try to expand along the first column.

Note that characteristic polynomial is $|\lambda I - A|$.

Answer (score 1):

Expand on the last row $$\det (A - \lambda I)=det \left(\begin{matrix} 
  -\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 &  -\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0&  -\lambda & 1 & 0\\
  0& 0 & 0 &  -\lambda & 1\\
  10^{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\lambda \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$ = 10^{10}-\lambda ^5$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the effect of $A$ on the canonical basis:
$$
Ae_1 = 10^{10} e_5,\quad
Ae_2 = e_1,\quad
Ae_3 = e_2,\quad
Ae_4 = e_3,\quad
Ae_5 = e_4
$$
Then $A^5 e_i = 10^{10} e_i$ and so $A^5 = 10^{10} I$.